# make first iteration in loop same speed as the rest

Tags: c#

I am trying to benchmark something.

I have a loop like

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
{
    Thing thing = createThing(i);

    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    thing.ComputationallyExpensiveOp();
    TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.Now - startTime;

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("i = " + i + "\ttime = " + elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
}
```

It looks like the first iteration, `i = 1`, takes a significant amount of time longer than it should (several orders of magnitude) based on how long the others take to complete.

The second iteration also seems too long often, although less obviously.

I feel like this is because the loop causes caching of a lot of values, which hadn't been set up in the first iteration.

Is there a way I can get the first iteration, `i = 1`, to be as "fast" (overhead-wise) as the rest, so that I really am timing *only* (as best as possible) `thing.ComputationallyExpensiveOp()`.

At the moment it's obvious that the first iteration is not an accurate reflection of `thing.ComputationallyExpensiveOp()`.

I tried already moving a "warm up" initialisation above the loop, but that didn't work.

```
Thing thing = createThing(1);
thing.ComputationallyExpensiveOp();

for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
{
    thing = createThing(i);

    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    thing.ComputationallyExpensiveOp();
    TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.Now - startTime;

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("i = " + i + "\ttime = " + elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
}
```

Comment: What kind of "warm up initialisation" did you try but didn't work? Normally calling the code that is to be benchmarked does work

Comment: @harold I edited to show. I am about to test copying also the `Conole.WriteLine` and timings etc.

Comment: Probably just time x loops, and print the median or average of the lot. Since it sounds like you can't control the caching happening in createThing()

Comment: How can we reasonably answer this without knowing what happens in CreateThing and ComputationallyExpensiveOp? What _caching_ is present in these two methods?

Comment: I copied the whole loop body above the loop and it seems to have "fixed" it. Ofc I can't be sure but the numbers look a lot more like expected now.

Comment: maybe ComputationallyExpensiveOp uses some cached data which is generated in the 1st (or 2nd) iteration.

Comment: @urlreader I wonder if it was `String.Format` ? — just realised this doesn't make sense, as it's outside the timed script. I really don't know what's going on. You're right, `ComputationallyExpensiveOp`, must be caching some data, but why wouldn't my ^^ first attempt at fixing it have worked?

Comment: Use the [Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch) class for measuring small timespans. It is more precise and lightweight than `DateTime.Now`. About the ComputationallyExpensiveOp, is it expected to be called frequently or rarely? If it's called rarely then you should be more interested for the **first** iteration, than for the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying *the whole*  loop body outside "fixed" it for me

```
Thing thing = createThing(1);

DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
thing.ComputationallyExpensiveOp();
TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.Now - startTime;

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("i = " + 1 + "\ttime = " + elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
{
    thing = createThing(i);

    startTime = DateTime.Now;
    thing.ComputationallyExpensiveOp();
    elapsed = DateTime.Now - startTime;

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("i = " + i + "\ttime = " + elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
}
```

I'm not really sure of the cause, but now the first iteration has a runtime more like expected.

Comment: I'm glad this solution worked for you. It remains an odd issue, however. Declaring the three variables outside the `for`-loop should not result in a noticable performance increase, especially not if the `thing.ComputationallyExpensiveOp()` call will consume most of the total processing power of your logic. If you get the chance for it, I would advise you to investigate this issue further. If the true origin of the issue remains undiscovered, you may find yourself confronted with a "spontaneous" reappearance of it sooner or later. And by then it might be harder to pinpoint and solve.

Comment: @BartHofland yeah I thought it was weird too, luckily it's not a part of anything I will be reusing in the future but I might investigate it again in a few days to update this SO post

Answer (score 1):

I have been using such `for`-loops for decades. And I never experienced, that such a `for`-loop was the cause of a delay during the first iteration.

I don't know anything about your `Thing` implementation, but I am quite sure the cause of your delay lies there. Not in the loop.

Comment: It's probably neither, but just that in C# the first time any method is called is slow because the code has not been JIT-compiled yet (so the time for JITting it is included in the benchmark, if you call cold code)

Comment: True, but unless `ComputationallyExpensiveOp` in the OP's isn't really that computationally expensive, JIT compiling doesn't explain a "several orders of magnitude" longer execution of the first iteration in that loop... I understand that JIT compiling has an overhead, but as I already said, I have never experienced such a delay caused by my compiler/environment in my entire career. It always primarily had to do with implementation details of the logic I developed.